# Who are these two people from the Avengers: Age of Ultron trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, character-identification, avengers-age-of-ultron

Near the start of the recently released *Age of Ultron* tailer is a wide-angle shot of what I assume is one of Stark's labs, with all of the Avengers in it plus three other people. One of them is Col. Rhodes, but who are the other two people supposed to be? They appear to be somehow connected to Thor and Steve Rogers, but otherwise I'm completely unsure.

[image: *Age of Ultron Screen* Cap]

Left to right, it seems to be Banner, Romanov, ??, Thor, Rogers, ??, Rhodes, Stark, Barton.

**Update:** Here is another angle as provided by the new footage after Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

[image]

Comment: Really hard to make out, but Maria Hill and possibly Scarlet Witch would make sense.

Comment: The one on the right is Maria Hill of SHIELD, the one on the left is an Asian actress whose name I can't recall, I think she might be a new character to the MCU.

Comment: It seems to be whomever [Kim Soo-hyun](http://comicbook.com/2014/10/23/who-is-mystery-woman-in-avengers-age-of-ultron-/) is playing.

Comment: @phantom42 Scarlet Witch is, afaict, still trapped wherever Ultron goes and gets her at this point.

Comment: I assumed it would have to be Maria Hill but for some reason I didn't think it looked anything like her from the front. Might be the civilian outfit.

Comment: Haha.. You have seen fake trailer..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now that the film has been released, we know who those two people are.

The woman in red is

> **Maria Hill** (Cobie Smulders), the former deputy director of SHIELD and now working in Stark’s HR department.

The woman standing beside Thor is

> **Helen Cho** (played by Claudia Kim), who’s a world-famous geneticist who is assisting the Avengers both in their tower in Manhattan, and from her office in Seoul.

See the [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/71220/revisions) for my guesses and speculation from before the film was released.

Comment: Confirmed by the clip released last night: Maria Hill is at that party, wearing that jacket.  Nice deduction!

Comment: @Nerrolken: Cheers, thanks for the heads-up. I haven't seen the clip yet. :)

Comment: Ah, well then allow me to do the honors!  :)  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGwuoYKhqx8

Comment: @alexwlchan http://www.justjared.com/2014/10/29/meet-claudia-kim-the-avengers-age-of-ultron-mystery-woman/

Comment: @Keen: Cheers. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @alexwlchan An extended trailer with a better shot of the mystery woman: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk24PuBUUkQ

Comment: Some more info on Claudia Kim and her role: http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/new-details-on-heroes-villains-arrive-with-avengers-age-of-ultron-character-descriptions

Answer (score 1):

Kim Soo-hyun is listed as "Doctor", but there is also an actress named [Leila Wong](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4837209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t23), who plays an unnamed "Korean Scientist".

and

Maria Hill, who went to work for Stark Industries after SHIELD collapsed (so it makes sense she would work in the Avengers Tower).

and

Colonel Rhodes.

Comment: It's worth noting that IMDB is essentially an unsourced Wiki.

Comment: @Keen - Are you saying that he might have the wong answer?

Comment: @Keen why? I can't think of any kind of more reliable source: " The data that is submitted goes through a series of consistency checks before it goes live." It's not a wiki whatsoever.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández Well, the actress' [own website](http://www.leilawong.com/#!page2/cc71) says she plays "Korean Hanbok Woman".  That sounds pretty different from 'Korean Scientist' to me.  IMDB takes submitted information, just like a Wiki.  Unlike Wikipedia, they don't bother to link to sources, so when bad information is posted (which happens often) it's hard to trace where it came from and why it's bad.  [See also.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Movie_Database#Copyright.2C_vandalism.2C_and_error_issues)

Comment: @Keen [Hanbok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbok) is traditional Korean dress.  So I guess it's kinda along the lines of "English pink-shirted woman", so unless she changes her whole outfit during the movie and that's just obfuscation, I don't think she's in the screenshot(s)

Comment: @JackBNimble http://www.justjared.com/2014/10/29/meet-claudia-kim-the-avengers-age-of-ultron-mystery-woman/

Comment: @JackBNimble An extended trailer with a better shot of the mystery woman: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk24PuBUUkQ

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I know from personal experience that IMDB allows wiki-style edits which are then *later* sometimes updated. I have friends who were extras on films and who added themselves to the IMDB credits for the film prior to release. When the final cast list was released by the studio, the cast list was updated and a lot of data was wiped out.